# was or did? What do I need to use?

Tags: grammar, past-continuous

1. I was reading poetry.

or

2. I did reading poetry.

What the option is right and why?

Comment: `was reading` or `did read`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I was reading poetry" is correct grammar. "I did reading poetry." is not.

More details:

1. "I was reading poetry" - Past imperfect tense - Emphasizes the action that happened. -  "At some time in the past, I was in the process of reading poetry."
2. "I did read poetry." - Past perfect tense - Emphasizes the *time* the action happened, or *confirms* the action was actually done (when someone says otherwise). - "I am confirming that I read poetry" (confirmation) or "I used to read poetry, but I don't do that anymore." (time)

Answer (score 1):

> **I was reading poetry**.

It was past continuous which talks about    a continuous activity at a point of time in the past.

> **I did reading poetry**.

The above sentence is wrong.

> **I did read poetry**.The sentence is correct.

The above  is not past perfect as  some user called it so but it is    simple past which is used to emphasize  an activity

Infact, I read poetry means( I did read poetry) since its negative is  I did not read poetry.

Comment: `I did reading poetry.` is another time?

Comment: I did reading  is possible  but not  reading  poetry is not possible

Comment: I did reading  is possible but   I did  reading poetry  is  not  possible